# How Synchronous/blocking are Events/Delegate subscriptions?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

How is this code going to behave through processing time ? (i.e, how synchronous is it ?)

```
public delegate void FooDelegate(bytes[] data);
public event FooDelegate FooEvent;

FooEvent += new FooDelegate(Process_X);
FooEvent += new FooDelegate(Process_Y);
FooEvent += new FooDelegate(Process_Z);

while (receiving)
{     
   byte[] data = getRealTimeData();

   StopWatch.Start();

   FooEvent(data);

   StopWatch.Stop();

   Console.Write(StopWatch.Elapsed.Millisec));
   StopWatch.Reset();
}
```

I have a couple of questions :

1. Will the call to FooEvent result in calling each subscription process sequentially/synchornously ? (Probably yes...)
2. Assuming each Process_N takes a long while to finish, will the call to each one block the chain (i.e the call to the next one) until it has finished ? If this is true, How to make the event call Processes X, Y, Z in a parallel fashion an then wait for all of them to finish, rather than calling them one by one and sequentially waiting for each one to finish ?

A few confirmations :

1. If the number of subscribers gets very high, I guess the Time printed by the StopWatch will get higher
2. If the processing logic in Process_N gets heavier, it will also affect the Time printed by the StopWatch

Comment: Have a search for 'parallel events', you'll find these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834130/events-with-task-parallel-library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516119/c-sharp-events-how-to-process-event-in-a-parallel-manner http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453655/parallel-event-handling-in-c-sharp

Comment: @gt : Sweet. Would you please post this as an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you'd benefit from parallelisation of your event handlers, as they will indeed execute sequentially and synchronously.

To create your custom event handlers you might write:

```
public event FooDelegate FooEvent
{
    add
    {
        // code to add an event handler
    }
    remove
    {
        // code to remove an event handler
    }
}
```

See the following questions for more information on what to do with the custom event handlers:

- [Events with Task Parallel Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834130/events-with-task-parallel-library) for .NET 4+
- [How to process events in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516119/c-sharp-events-how-to-process-event-in-a-parallel-manner)
- [Parallel event handling in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453655/parallel-event-handling-in-c-sharp)
- etc.

and Jon Skeet's page on [delegates and events](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/events.html).

Answer (score 1):

1: yes
2: yes
It has to events might return results.

But: you should implement your event-handlers in a way so that they don't take long to run!
If they have to do heavy lifting consider running the computation in a task that get's started in your event-handeler.

Comment: Should this task call subscribers in a parallel fashion ?

Comment: no if the event-handlers don't do much you can have the calls as they are - the point is having handlers that do only short computations